# Data entered 2 times after run the query in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have faced another problem please help.
when i query to my db 1 time, 2 rows entered into the db!

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$famil = $_POST['famil'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);
$famil = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $famil);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
$amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $amount);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users".
"(name, famil, email, amount)".
"VALUES ('$name','$famil','$email','$amount')";

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Data entered successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error entering data: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and the result after 2 times run this code:

```
3   mohsen  gholi   ***@yahoo.com   235354346
4   mohsen  gholi   ***@yahoo.com   235354346
5   mohsen  gholi   ***@yahoo.com   235354346
6   mohsen  gholi   ***@yahoo.com   235354346
```

Comment: @nadaram please do not deface your question after asking it, and being answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line as said by Fred

```
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

and just use:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Data entered successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error entering data: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: after the data entry i want to redirect to other page, but it doesn't redirect with the code : header("Location: $go");

Comment: Please specify "$go" in header locations. And , if you transfer thorough this method then that will be shown in the url, and so it will have limits on the character.

Comment: I was facing the same problem. Can you please tell me why it is executing IF statement?